# Replace value in file with value from another file based on matching string (otherwise: skip)

Tags: bash, unix, join, awk

I have two files and I want to replace some lines in *file1* with lines from *file2* based on matching a pattern, **without** removing the lines in *file1* that had no match in *file2*.

File1 :

```
1     a
2     b
3     d
4     c
```

File 2:

```
2     banana
4     chocolate
```

File 3:

```
1     a
2     banana
3     d
4     chocolate
```

This is what I have:

> join -11 -21 -e0 -o'1.1,2.2' <(sort -k1 file1.txt) <(sort -k1
>   file2.txt) > file3.txt

...but it removes the lines with no match in file2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {print $1,$1 in a?a[$1]:$2}' OFS="\t"  Input_file2   Input_file1
```

Add `>  file3.txt` to above code to get the output into output filw named `file3.txt` too.